# Integração NFSe Prefeitura de São Paulo retorna Bad Request

Tags: php, soap, nfe

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP para gerar NFSe que utiliza o Web Service da prefeitura de São Paulo, mas não estou conseguindo fazer a integração com o Web Service. Sempre que envio uma mensagem XML para o Web Service, eu recebo uma resposta com as seguintes informações:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 21 Jun 2018 13:25:20 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Para fazer a requisição de teste, estou utilizando o SoapUI 5.2.1.

Exemplo de requisição “ConsultaCNPJ” que está dando erro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <ConsultaCNPJRequest xmlns="http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe">
      <VersaoSchema>1</VersaoSchema>
      <MensagemXML>
          <PedidoConsultaCNPJ>
              <Cabecalho Versao="1">
                <CPFCNPJRemetente>
                  <CNPJ>CNPJ x</CNPJ>
                </CPFCNPJRemetente>
              </Cabecalho>
            <CNPJContribuinte>
            <CNPJ>CNPJ Y</CNPJ>
            </CNPJContribuinte>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <SignedInfo>
                  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                  <Reference>
                      <Transforms>
                      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3c.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                      </Transforms>
                      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                      <DigestValue>HuMpzsiKXGJw7yduTCts0=</DigestValue>
                  </Reference>
              </SignedInfo>
              <SignatureValue>F0Te8gclpt0pW0BNBPCxknBFXs+igy/VvSM6zvy1agZGcv7ZiYWjzdMNB4G4ANeBPtpWI0hDae0/ZNHzXvUSHUJ+V+PANNCsKj1IAKNn4Sbv1DV4gPj15p4SUzpE4Lee5LvD37fPxx5VALRcWKLQoPL+ViOG+4S5npVcXpurr8HUZvhVkA3ilvNJMGf701q0oCJ/ttil0wo8xl2MaBoqywaTLD1PN5AjS/koFo7A+/ozOSCzIdojXWTIk2NLugYATZ9Trrrckx7TJb3QkBvj6TQg9H6r64Qy9bLxZWIhETrou/lCIAqXqsNvi8wsBYAwcF+R18CsqDw==</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <X509Data>
                </X509Certificate>
                  exemplo1
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
          </PedidoConsultaCNPJ>
      </MensagemXML>
    </ConsultaCNPJRequest>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Alguém tem um exemplo de requisição válida? Ou sabe porque está dando esse erro?

Comment: Estou passando pelo mesmo problema. Vc conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Também estou com o mesmo problema para desenvolver um requerimento em Python.
Consigo fazer para o SEFAZ utilizando os webservices do Governo do Estado de SP (https://portal.fazenda.sp.gov.br/servicos/nfe/Paginas/URL-WEBSERVICES.aspx)

Porém não consigo para a Nota do Milhão (Prefeitura de Sao Paulo), além do schema do envelope ser diferente, recebo STATUS 400 (BAD REQUEST) porém não retorna nenhuma informação de erro. Já liguei na prefeitura e nada.

No link do web service detalha a seguinte estrutura:

https://nfe.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/ws/lotenfe.asmx?op=ConsultaCNPJ

> POST /ws/lotenfe.asmx HTTP/1.1 Host: nfe.prefeitura.sp.gov.br
>   Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length:
>   length

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <ConsultaCNPJRequest xmlns="http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe">
      <VersaoSchema>int</VersaoSchema>
      <MensagemXML>string</MensagemXML>
    </ConsultaCNPJRequest>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Aparentemente seu envelope está correto, verifique se a sua assinatura com seu certificado está correta no seu xml.

Answer (score 0):

A integração da prefeitura de SP espera receber um XML transformado em string, por isso meu XML enviado via soap UI não funcionava. No php basta usar o método saveXML para fazer essa transformação após assinar o XML

Comment: Eu estou passando pelo mesmo problema. Tentei "escapar" o xml do MensagemXML e até mesmo todo o xml mas ainda recebo o erro 400-Bad request.

Answer (score 0):

aqui ainda não consegui, estou utilizando o Postman para fazer um requerimento, recebo o erro de Bad Request 400, mas sem nenhuma mensagem de erro, então fica difícil de resolver.

Meu envelope está no seguinte formato:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <ConsultaCNPJRequest xmlns="http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe">
      <VersaoSchema>1</VersaoSchema>
      <MensagemXML>
        <Cabecalho>
        <Versao>"1"</Versao>
    <CNPJRemetente>
      <CNPJ>NUMERO</CNPJ>
    </CNPJRemetente>
    </Cabecalho>
  <CNPJContribuinte>
    <CNPJ>NUMERO</CNPJ>
  </CNPJContribuinte>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/></Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>pT6zm/meXT3rusPi6VAEaQ68IFQ=</DigestValue></Reference>
</SignedInfo><SignatureValue>"ASSINATURA BASE64"</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>CONTEUDO DO CERTIFICADO EM BASE64</X509Certificate>
</X509Data></KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</MensagemXML>
</ConsultaCNPJRequest>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: Se você enviar o XML nesse formato via Postman não vai funcionar, tem que converter para string. Nessa conversão, o XML é escapado (escaped).

Comment: Daniel, obrigado pela informação... Estou fazendo dessa maneira, sem quebra de linha e formatação pelo Postman e em Python Request também, no entanto continuo recebendo Bad Request sem retorno nenhum sobre o erro. Você teria algum exemplo funcional para eu comparar por favor? Obg! Abraçs